# Diversity in this stack, and addressing the difficulties of neurodivirse user base. at TWP

Tags: discussion

Since TWP has a very large userbase from IT, and there is a much higher prevelance of autism in high tech fields in general [See this study,](https://consumer.healthday.com/cognitive-health-information-26/autism-news-51/more-autism-diagnoses-in-high-tech-areas-study-finds-654206.html) An effort should be made to be more welcoming of people on the spectrum on this site.

For ease of reading, I will use the following abbreviations.

ASD = Autism Spectrum Disorder
AS = Asperger's Syndrome

## A modest proposal

1. When dealing with a user, or a question regarding ASD , the **ASSUME GOOD INTENTIONS RULE** is one to keep in mind.  One thing that is endemic of the autism spectrum (including AS) is, an apparent lack of empathy as discussed in [THIS ARTICLE](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2695286/) which combined with the literalism, and apparent pedantic choice of language may make their language and word choices seem abrasive, brash, callous, or insensitive.  Assume good intentions and explain, when possible.
2. When answering questions about ASD and AS, precision of language, a logical approach, and quantifying over qualifying language is most helpful.  When providing answers to questions regarding ASD and AS at the workplace, logical arguments are far more effective in addressing the issues than emotional ones.
3. Many people with ASD/AS have difficulty with literalism, this makes them come across as being deliberately obtuse, or even as coming across as a smart-ass.  Again, assume good intentions, try to be patient, and be more precise in your language.
4. Be careful with your own language.  People with ASD/AS are among the most marginalized in society, being both misunderstood and lacking in communication skills.  A person ASD/AS may make an unintentional verbal slip, and come across as rude or abrasive, and then face the embarrassment of being berated for doing such.  Think about this for a moment.  Would you berate a deaf person and tell them they need to listen, or tell a blind person to watch where they're going?  Please extend the same understanding to people on the spectrum.  Don't berate someone for not understanding you the first time, or assume ill intent.
5. Understand that people with ASD/AS have much to contribute, edit for tone if need be, and appreciate the depth of knowledge they have.  One of the effects that ASD has on a person's reasoning is a tendency to plumb the depths of an issue and to examine things in details.
6. Binary thinking.  Be aware that some issues will confuse people with autism on this site.  If something applies in one situation, and not another, a person with autism may be confused as to why.  For example, in a more formal work environment, he may not understand why you address the boss as Mr Smith instead of "Roy", when you can address your coworker as "bob".  The social rules of a workplace may be second nature to someone who is neurotypical, but not to someone on the spectrum, so more detailed explanations may be needed.

Hopefully, this will make it easier for people answering/interacting with people on the spectrum here at TWP.

Comment: Should people with ASD/AS self-identify as such in their question (*and perhaps in a tag*)? That way folks would know to apply a different set of "rules" as you have expressed above. Also the folks who don't want to bother spending extra time with your suggestions, could more easily avoid the question at hand.

Comment: Assuming good intentions is a good rule to follow without regard to ASD/AS.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere agree, the assuming good intentions needs to be observed far more in general, and just doing so would take a huge burden off of autistics.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Well, is it really a different set of rules to accommodate a disability?  Don't we cut curbs for people in wheelchairs, have braille keypads for ATMs?  Chirping crosswalk signals to allow the blind to know when to cross?  Lights on phones for the hearing impaired, and even relay systems for them?

Comment: I think you are conflating a different set of issues now. Certainly you aren't proposing that questions/answers be downvoted or closed because they aren't sufficiently "ASD/AS accessible" are you?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere oh, no not at all, just suggesting some things to people that might make it easier.  Not suggesting any policy changes or change to voting.

Comment: Okay, sounds good. Curb cuts are required. Handicap toilet stalls are required. Writing clearer questions using precise language sticking to logical arguments is suggested.

Comment: Thank you Richard.  I hope there are some who will heed your call for more empathy and understanding and less judgement and vitriol.  Sadly it seems to not be the case in this very question.

Comment: Just came to my attention that we have an [autism-spectrum](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autism-spectrum) tag.

Answer (score 11):

Since you value directness, I'll be direct (what I would otherwise consider too blunt).

You have good intentions, but you're going about this wrong.  You're asking for special treatment, mistargeting in the process, and using your disability as a weapon.  Also, your proposal has a large logical flaw.

**Assume good intentions applies to everybody.**  That includes autistics.  Making accusations about the behavior of others isn't assuming good intentions either.

**You seek special rules that place the entire burden on the community and none on the autistic.**  If someone is having trouble understanding an answer because literalism or binary thinking or something else is getting in the way, then that person should ask for clarification or even suggest an edit.  Since by your own description most people do not think in quite that way, you should expect to do some of the work here.  Relatedly, you need to *assume good intentions* if your edit is rejected; sometimes an edit to address one thing makes another thing worse.

**Using a disability as a bludgeon or excuse is not ok.**  Well-adjusted people with disabilities (in which group I count myself) do what they can for themselves and ask for help and understanding for the rest. That first part is important.  You say that we need to accept language that is (you wrote "seem", as if to excuse it) "abrasive, brash, callous, or insensitive".  No, actually, we don't; when *anybody* is being rude we should edit, and if editing isn't possible or is rejected we need to delete the offending content.  "But I'm autistic and that's how I am" is not an excuse.

Finally, **you assume that all and only questions about autism are asked by autistics.**  You want us to treat *questions about autism* differently, but don't you think autistics have questions about resumes and dress codes and time-management too?  And don't you think that some, perhaps even the majority, of questions involving autism are asked by *people who are not autistic* who are trying to interact with coworkers who are?  And don't you think that both autistics and neurotypical people might be reading *any* content on this site?  Your proposal does not do what you seek.

---

We have a Code of Conduct that applies to everybody.  We expect people to assume good intentions, to treat each other decently, and to be open-minded and welcoming.  If *anybody's* behavior falls afoul of the CoC, we need to deal with it.  We don't need extra rules for one category of people, and no group or individual gets to evade responsibility for following it by declaring special circumstances.

Comment: It's not a bludgeon to point out that some people have difficulties, and how to help those with difficulties.  You wouldn't say to a blind person who bumped into you, then said "sorry I'm blind" with "Quit using your blindness to bludgeon those of us who can see".  This answer is 100% NOT assuming good intentions.

Comment: So you wanted me to dress this up in "I perceive"s and "perhaps"s and weasel words, *against your explicit requests for people to be blunt with you*?  So I *shouldn't* respect your wishes?  Or is this a case of "damned if you do, damned if you don't" and the only way to win is not to play (answer)?  'Cause if it's that last, then we have a bigger problem.

Comment: No, I just find it amusing that a moderator is ignoring both the "be nice" rule and the "assume good intentions" rule, and is engaging in behavior that if I did the same, would earn at least a two weeks suspension, if not longer, all while criticizing me for allegedly wanting two sets of rules.

Comment: You're doing it again.  You're *asserting* that I'm ignoring the rules, instead of looking for an interpretation that assumes good intent.  Do you not see the irony in that?

Comment: Very good attempt at character assassination, and I walked into it.  Back to the simple facts.  Every last conclusion you make in your points are misrepresentations of my intent.  1)I have said both in my post and comments to Joe that the problem is that the "assume good intentions" rule is not being followed, and that doing so would benefit everyone 2)Again, in my post and in my comments, I've stated that these are not rules I'm suggestiing, but information on how to make it more welcoming by pointing out the difficulties autistics have.  3)In **EVERY** answer I have **EVER** posted, ....

Comment: ... I have included the phrase "A diagnosis is not destiny, nor is it an excuse" and then added that the behavior needs to be corrected, so your accusation of my wanting to use disabilities as a bludgeon, is a false claim.  Lastly, Nowhere have I **EVER** made the assumption that all questions asked about autism are asked by autistics, and my **SECOND HIGHEST RATED ANSWER**  is to a question someone is asking about an autistic coworker.

While I do appreciate the bluntness of your response, I do not appreicate the falsehoods within, and the very snark which you claim is why you avoid chat.

Comment: Lastly, there is no irony in pointing out an obvious attempt to bait someone into a rant.  I'm kicking myself over this now, as I allowed you to use elements from private conversations to bait me into an irritated response.  What I posted in this discussion is right out of the DSM IV and DSM IV, although paraphrased, so if you have any issues with it, I suggest you take it up with the American Psychological association, and the authors of those books.

Comment: You're making some *very* serious accusations, @Richard.  If you believe I have misused my moderator position or am in violation of site rules, then you owe it to the community to raise your complaint with SE so they can investigate.  If you don't actually believe that, then you owe me an apology for your false claims/errors.  (I have no idea what private conversation you're referring to, by the way.)  Until you do one or the other, I'm done discussing this with you.

Comment: As someone with ASD, I broadly agree with this answer. I've always seen it as my responsbility to ensure my conduct, be it in my nature or not, does not unduely disrupt the operation of any groups I'm a part of. It's not in my interest to be coddled by any community in particular, especially with respect to personality flaws of mine that will work against me in a real life workplace scenario.

Comment: To clarify that further, there is nothing wrong and I'd argue it's very much in good spirit to keep in mind someone's perspective when judging intent, and assuming good faith is always a prerogative here, but my mental issues (including things like literalism, becoming hung up on specific language, and other things mentioned here) are mine to deal with and I cannot expect members of the stack to treat me any differently then a normal user because of them. If someone is rude, they're rude.  Whether they are that to me or any other user _should_ be immaterial

Answer (score 5):

> Hopefully, this will make it easier for people answering/interacting
>   with people on the spectrum here at TWP.

If a question self-identifies the author as ASD/AS, then it makes sense to try to keep your suggestions in mind as much as we can when crafting an answer. I'll try to remember to do that.

I'd suggest a tag could help, and I'll let you craft the text of the tag.

Still, since the site is aimed at the general population, we have to expect most folks to give general answers, not all of which will be finely tuned. Certainly the majority of question authors cannot be expected to follow all of your suggestions every time, just because some of the readers might be ASD/AS. We'll have to all do our best and assume positive intent of everyone.

Comment: agreed, I think that assuming good intent as a general rule will benefit everyone in general